# Create a 'detailed' page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page with a few buttons, which are generated by a function and displayed through a short-code. I want to link these buttons to `wp-content/plugin/nameplugin/detailedPage.php?id=blabla`.

Do I need to create a new function or a new PHP page. And if I need to create a new PHP page, how do I get the header/sidebar/footer from the chosen theme of the Wordpress website?

Answer (score 0):

Better off passing URL query parameters to the same page, and dealing with them in your shortcode's logic. i.e. keep it all on the one page and switch the output based on query parameters.